# Why can't I get QuartzScheduler to trigger my job?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

Im trying to run a small QuartzScheduler application with a cron trigger.

I think I have the basic properties set to get up and running and I see the log output as follows:

```
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM scheduler.QuartzScheduler start
INFO: QuartzScheduler started...
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl <init>
INFO: Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler <init>
INFO: Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.0 created.
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore initialize
INFO: RAMJobStore initialized.
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler initialize
INFO: Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.0) 'QuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory instantiate
INFO: Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.0
Mar 27, 2020 12:11:16 PM org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler start
INFO: Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

From what I can see in the logs it seems the scheduler has started although I don't see any 
of the log statements I have in the Job class that should be triggering.
According to the tutorial I'm following the log outputs looks as expected but i'm not sure why I cannot see the log info for the actual job being ran.

My QuartzScheduler class:

```
public class QuartzScheduler {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzScheduler.class);

    private static final String TRIGGER_NAME = "fileCheckerTrigger";
    private static final String JOB_NAME = "fileCheckerJob";
    private static final String CRON_EXPRESSION = "0 30 16-21 ? * * *";
    private static final String DUM_CRON_EXP = "0 0/5 0 ? * * *";//every 5 minutes todo: remove when done testing

    private Scheduler scheduler;

    public void start() throws Exception {
        logger.info("QuartzScheduler started...");

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "1");
        p.put("org.quartz.jobStore.class", "org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore");

        //Scheduler class links both “Job” and “Trigger” together and executes it.
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(p);
        scheduler = factory.getScheduler();

        scheduleJob(buildCronSchedulerTrigger("cronGroup"), QuartzJob.class, "cronGroup");
        scheduler.start();
        //scheduler.shutdown();
    }

    private void scheduleJob(Trigger trigger, Class jobClass, String groupName) throws Exception {

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(JOB_NAME, groupName).build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    private Trigger buildCronSchedulerTrigger(String groupName) {
        return TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger().withIdentity(TRIGGER_NAME, groupName)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                        .cronSchedule(DUM_CRON_EXP))
                .build();
    }
}
```

My QuartzJob class:

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzJob.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info(" File checking task initiated. ");
    }
}
```

My app class with main:

```
public class FileWatcherApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        QuartzScheduler scheduler = new QuartzScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    }
}
```

I'm expect to see **File checking task initiated** in the log but haven't been successful in doing so. I'm using a temporary cron expression which should trigger the job every 5 minutes...

Hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong or not understanding.